# Identifying XPATH of HTML element for web scraping python code

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to practice creating building a web page scraping Python code using chromedriver and selenium. I need to instruct the code to click the "Check-In Date" field (done) and then click next  3x to go to the month of September. I'm having trouble identifying the right XPATH-- can someone help identify the XPATH or advise on a different way to get the element?

This is what I've tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://secure.webrez.com//Bookings105/activity-edit.html?table=hotels&listing_id=1964&mode=command&command=bookingrequestform&hotel_id=1964&_ga=2.105908291.1942037294.1687828631-724636554.1687828631&_gl=1*jbwd53*_ga*NzI0NjM2NTU0LjE2ODc4Mjg2MzE.*_ga_GP9HE5JR9Q*MTY4NzgyODYzMS4xLjAuMTY4NzgyODYzOC4wLjAuMA..)')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='dpicker_date_from']").click()

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//th[@name='next available']").click()
```

The error I get is "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//th[@name='next available']"}"

See screenshot for HTML code of the element (the next button on the calendar pop up).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrIyc.png)